# Why my update query is slow ever after enough RAM and CPU?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We are running following query in latest MariaDB virtual server.

We have following tables and both have 30K records in it and we are running a query.

Update is too slow , may be due to large no of columns, we have enought cpu and ram.

CPU : 16 core , RAM : 62 GB

Also my.cnf settings are given bellow,

Can someone check and guide us.

```
        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_timezone_minutes;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_timezone_minutes (
            TimezonesID int,
            VendorConnectionID int,
            AccessType varchar(200),
            CountryID int,
            City varchar(100) COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            Tariff varchar(50),
            Code varchar(100),
            OriginationCode varchar(100),       
            OriginationCode2 varchar(100),      
            OriginationCode2_Rows varchar(100), 

            CostPerMinute DECIMAL(18,8), 
            OutpaymentPerMinute DECIMAL(18,8),
            SurchargePerMinute DECIMAL(18,8),

            OutpaymentPerCall DECIMAL(18,8), 
            Surcharges DECIMAL(18,8),
            SurchargePerCall DECIMAL(18,8),
            CollectionCostAmount DECIMAL(18,8),
            CostPerCall DECIMAL(18,8),

            minute_CostPerMinute DECIMAL(18,2), 
            minute_OutpaymentPerMinute DECIMAL(18,2),
            minute_SurchargePerMinute DECIMAL(18,2),

            calls_OutpaymentPerCall DECIMAL(18,2), 
            calls_Surcharges DECIMAL(18,2), 
            calls_SurchargePerCall DECIMAL(18,2), 
            calls_CollectionCostAmount DECIMAL(18,2), 
            calls_CostPerCall DECIMAL(18,2)  



        );



        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_accounts;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_accounts (
            ID int auto_increment,
            TimezonesID  int,
            VendorConnectionID int,
            AccessType varchar(200),
            CountryID int,
            City varchar(100) COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            Tariff varchar(50),
            Code varchar(100),
            OriginationCode varchar(100),
            OriginationCode2 varchar(100),

            _Minutes int,
            _Calls int,


            Primary Key (ID )

        );





UPDATE  tmp_timezone_minutes tzm
                        INNER JOIN tmp_accounts a on tzm.VendorConnectionID = a.VendorConnectionID
                        SET minute_CostPerMinute = ( IFNULL((select  (@p_Minutes - tzmd2.minute_CostPerMinute) 
                                                                            from tmp_timezone_minutes_3 tzmd2 WHERE  tzmd2.VendorConnectionID = a.VendorConnectionID /*AND tzmd2.TimezonesID = a.TimezonesID*/ AND tzmd2.AccessType = a.AccessType AND tzmd2.CountryID = a.CountryID /*AND tzmd2.OriginationCode = a.OriginationCode*/ AND tzmd2.Code = a.Code AND tzmd2.City = a.City 
                                                                            AND tzmd2.Tariff = a.Tariff AND tzmd2.CostPerMinute IS NOT NULL AND tzmd2.OriginationCode2 = @p_Origination  LIMIT 1 ),_Minutes) )   
                                                        / (select IF(count(*) = 0,1,count(*))  from tmp_timezone_minutes_2 tzmd WHERE tzmd.VendorConnectionID = a.VendorConnectionID AND tzmd.TimezonesID = a.TimezonesID AND tzmd.AccessType = a.AccessType AND tzmd.CountryID = a.CountryID AND tzmd.OriginationCode = a.OriginationCode AND tzmd.Code = a.Code AND tzmd.City = a.City 
                                                        AND tzmd.Tariff = a.Tariff AND tzmd.CostPerMinute IS NOT NULL) 
                        WHERE  tzm.TimezonesID = a.TimezonesID AND tzm.VendorConnectionID = a.VendorConnectionID AND tzm.AccessType = a.AccessType AND tzm.CountryID = a.CountryID AND tzm.OriginationCode = a.OriginationCode AND tzm.Code = a.Code AND tzm.City = a.City 
                                                    AND tzm.Tariff = a.Tariff AND tzm.CostPerMinute IS NOT NULL and (tzm.OriginationCode2 != @p_Origination)

/* Affected rows: 17,820  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 00:07:31 */
```

We have many such queries with condition like "minute_CostPerMinute =",   "CostPerMinute IS NOT NULL" 
replaced with different columns like OutpaymentPerMinute , SurchargePerMinute etc. so not sure what index it will suits more.

here is my.cnf file.

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=55834574848
sort_buffer_size=52428800
join_buffer_size=52428800
read_rnd_buffer_size=52428800
max_sort_length=8388608
max_length_for_sort_data=1048
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=90
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_size=52428800
query_cache_limit=52428800
thread_cache_size=90
max_connections=500
max_heap_table_size=9663676416
tmp_table_size=9663676416
max_allowed_packet=52428800
table_open_cache=300
innodb_log_buffer_size=1073741824
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=4
innodb_page_cleaners=4
group_concat_max_len=1048576
```

Thanks

Comment: This is redeemable using indexes.  Keep changeable elements like minute_CostPerMinute further in the right of the index. Take a look [at constructing indexes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1) from the JOIN and WHERE criteria. It would be easier to read if it was [formatted](http://sqlformat.org/). Why temporary tables?

Comment: You are `UPDATEing` an empty table?  The `UPDATE` won't do anything!  Please show us the SQL without using temp tables.

Comment: `max_heap_table_size` and `tmp_table_size` are dangerously high; don't set them to more than 1% of RAM.  Most of your `DECIMAL` declarations take 9 bytes and allow for ridiculously huge values.  Suggest you trim them back to reasonable sizes.

Comment: Updating 17820 rows takes time.  Do you need to do that many?  Can it be broken into smaller chunks?

Answer (score 0):

RAM and CPU rarely are the problem with slow queries.  Usually, it is indexing and/or formulation.

(See Comments for other critique.)

```
            WHERE  tzmd.VendorConnectionID = a.VendorConnectionID
              AND  tzmd.TimezonesID = a.TimezonesID
              AND  tzmd.AccessType = a.AccessType
              AND  tzmd.CountryID = a.CountryID
              AND  tzmd.OriginationCode = a.OriginationCode
              AND  tzmd.Code = a.Code
              AND  tzmd.City = a.City
              AND  tzmd.Tariff = a.Tariff
```

Do you have a multi-column ("composite") index on most of those columns?  If not, pick the 5 most selective columns and make an `INDEX` with them, in any order.